# Increasing count of colors instead of 8

Tags: image, matlab, processing

I have completed a programming that can count up to 8 colors in images by using the RGB method from 000 up to 111. I need to do some modification to it. So far I declare the number if above 128 will equal to 1 & below 128 will be 0. It will count the 8 colours. How to increase the number of colours count if let say I do it partially from 0-64,65-128,129-192,193-255.

```
count=zeros(1,8);
for i = 1:w 
    for j = 1:h

        if redChannel(i,j) > 128,
            aredChannel2 = 1;
        else
            aredChannel2=0;
        end
        quantizedImage(i,j,1)=aredChannel2*255;

        if greenChannel(i,j) > 128,
            agreenChannel2 = 1;
        else
            agreenChannel2=0;
        end
        quantizedImage(i,j,2)=agreenChannel2*255;

        if blueChannel(i,j) > 128,
            ablueChannel2 = 1;
        else
            ablueChannel2=0;
        end
        quantizedImage(i,j,3)=ablueChannel2*255;

        bin=4*aredChannel2+2*agreenChannel2+ablueChannel2+1;

        count(bin)=count(bin)+1;

    end
end

figure, imshow(uint8(quantizedImage))
```

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the number of intervals increases the base you are counting in: instead of `2^3=8` quantized colors you will have `4^3=64` quantized colors.

```
rgb = imread( ... ); %// read you image here
qImage = zeros( size(rgb(:,:,1)) ); %// preallocate result
intervals = permute([64, 128, 192, 256], [1 3 2]); %// the quantization intervals
base = numel(intervals);
for ci=1:size(rgb,3) %// for each channel
    whichInterval = bsxfun( @le, rgb(:,:,ci), intervals ); %// select per pixel, which interval is relevant
    [~, q] = max( whichInterval, [], 3 ); %// get index of relevant interval
    qImage = qImage*base + (q-1); %// -1 to convert from matlab's 1-based indexing
end
```

Comment: No problem :)  I actually did not notice until about a few hours later!  I was just gazing at your very elegant solution with `permute` and `bsxfun`.  Very nicely done.

Comment: @rayryeng hey I couldnt understand it. can I just use the if else to make it more specific? and how about the count?
 
 bin=4*aredChannel2+2*agreenChannel2+ablueChannel2+1;

        count(bin)=count(bin)+1;

Comment: @RabaniAhmadTasman try to break the code into statements and see what they do. A nested loop with many `if` clauses is a terrible way of coding in Matlab.